# .copyfromrecordset not responding

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have the below code which is copying data from a spreadsheet database which I have established a connection with and pasting it in the active workbook. There are 6 cases that it checks for, and depending on the case it it opens a recordset for the specific sheet.

For 5 out of 6 cases, this works swimmingly. For the 6th case, the line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JobOrders").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset
```

makes Excel Not Respond for about 15-20 seconds, and then it will continue to execute afterwords. I am at a complete loss on this. Below is what I believe to be all the relevant code.

```
        Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
        dbFile = dbPath & SheetArr(i)
        Set objFile = objFSO.getfile(dbFile)
        objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & dbFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMX=0"";"
        ...
        Case Is = 4
            objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [Database$]", objConnection
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Cells.WrapText = False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            objRecordset.Close
            objConnection.Close
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts").Cells(1, 17).value = Now
        Case Is = 5
            objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [Documents$]", objConnection
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Documents").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Documents").Cells.WrapText = False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            objRecordset.Close
            objConnection.Close
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts").Cells(1, 8).value = Now
        Case Is = 6
            objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [JobOrders$]", objConnection
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JobOrders").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JobOrders").Cells.WrapText = False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            objRecordset.Close
            objConnection.Close
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts").Cells(1, 29).value = Now
    End Select
End If
Next i
```

Any help would be very appreciated! Let me know if you need more or have questions!

Comment: How large is `JobOrders` sheet in terms of rows and columns?

Comment: @Parfait I am copying the whole sheet, but the actual amount of data in the sheet is very small at this point. Maybe 10-15 rows of data with 30 columns.

Comment: Have you checked the `UsedRange.Address` for that `JobOrders` sheet? It might be that it's absurdly larger than what you expect to see for that particular.

Comment: @this you nailed it. My usedrange was enormous. I was able to delete all of the unwanted rows/columns and, combined with the more efficient code from the answer below its working like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

While your situation is not too reproducible, possibly how your objects are uilitized might be the problem. Consider a DRY-er approach since you appear to be running nested `For`, `If`, and `Select`.

- Since all `Case` blocks are virtually the same, use them only to assign the SQL statement, worksheet name, and contact sheet column number
- Keep database objects, `objConncection` and `objRecordset`, near each other and open/close after needed querying and outputting task
- Use `With` blocks to avoid repeating object and better organize methods and properties
- Try releasing all objects with `Set obj = Nothing`

Refactored Code

```
For i = ...
    ...
    If ...
        myConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                 "Data Source=" & dbFile & _
                 ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMX=0"";"

        Select Case ...
            ...
            Case Is = 4
                mySql = "Select * FROM [Database$]"
                mySheet = "Database"
                myContactCol = 17

            Case Is = 5
                mySql = "Select * FROM [Documents$]"
                mySheet = "Documents"
                myContactCol = 8

            Case Is = 6
                mySql = "Select * FROM [JobOrders$]"
                mySheet = "JobOrders"
                myContactCol = 29

        End Select

        objConnection.Open myConn                       ' OPEN CONNECTION
        objRecordset.Open mySql                         ' OPEN RECORDSET
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet)
            .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset
            .Cells.WrapText = False
        End With
        objRecordset.Close                              ' CLOSE RECORDSET
        objConnection.Close                             ' CLOSE CONNECTION

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts").Cells(1, myContactCol).value = Now
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        ' RELEASE SET OBJECTS
        Set objFile = Nothing: Set objFSO = Nothing
        Set objRecordset = Nothing: Set objConnection = Nothing
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: This code looks much more efficient than what I have, and I have put it in my sheet. I looked at the usedrange.address, and that is crazy big, which is probably what's causing the issue. How do you reduce that to what is actually being used?